# Operating on while loop outside the loop matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, while-loop

i've got problems with my Nucleo.

Im using Matlab to cooperate with my Nucleo board.

I want to build programmatically GUI with buttons, figures etc. I'm going to put whole functionality in while loop. And now there's my question.

Is there any posibility to put whole code in while loop and operate it through callback functions outside the loop?
For example: Im my loop i want to send some data to Nucleo on btn1 press, and i want to stop it on btn2 press(Of course if statements for btns). Is there possibility to do it by changing the button values or something like that(Flags etc.)?

I don't want use global variables.

Comment: Why a while loop? Read up about how to code a MATLAB GUI. It all works with callbacks, you don’t need a loop.

Comment: I need while loop beacuse later on, board will receive live data from PPG sensor and send it to the matlab. I want to execute every functionality avoiding global variables

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible...
It's not the best programming pattern, but it's very convenient approach for small software projects.

I recommend you to use [MATLAB App Designer](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/app-designer.html).
App Designer uses OOP programming model, that makes it simpler to pass data (without using global variables, and without complicated solutions that are used with GUIDE).

Here is a sample instructions:

1. Start App Designer - execute `appdesigner` from command line.
2. Add two buttons, and two labels (add anything else later).
3. Add callbacks: for start button set flag to `true` and in stop button to `false`.
   The syntax is `app.is_sending = true` (when `is_sending` is a property of `app`).
4. Change from *Design View* to *Code View*.
5. Add private properties: `loop_counter = 0;`, `sending_counter = 0;`, `is_sending = false;`.
6. Add callback - select `startupFcn` callback function.
7. Put your while loop in the `startupFcn` callback.
   Use `while isvalid(app)`
8. Place your while loop functionality inside the while loop.
9. Place your sending code with `if (app.is_sending)`...
10. **Very important**: at the end of the loop call `pause` function.
    You must execute `pause` or `drawnow` to allow callbacks to be responsive.

When using App Designer, some code is generated automatically, and cannot be modified in Code View.
The following code sample includes both generated code, and customized code:

```
classdef app1 < matlab.apps.AppBase

    % Properties that correspond to app components
    properties (Access = public)
        UIFigure            matlab.ui.Figure
        StartSendingButton  matlab.ui.control.Button
        StopSendingButton   matlab.ui.control.Button
        Sending0Label       matlab.ui.control.Label
        LoopCounter0Label   matlab.ui.control.Label
    end


    properties (Access = private)
        loop_counter = 0 % Count while loop iteration
        sending_counter = 0; %Count only while "sending data"
        is_sending = false;  %Flag: if value is true, assume "sending"
    end


    % Callbacks that handle component events
    methods (Access = private)

        % Code that executes after component creation
        function startupFcn(app)
            %While loop: loop until app is not valid.
            while isvalid(app)
                %Place your while loop functionality here:
                %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                app.loop_counter = app.loop_counter + 1; %Increase loop counter
                app.LoopCounter0Label.Text = ['Loop Counter: ', num2str(app.loop_counter)]; %Update loop coouner text lable.
                %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

                %Place your sending code here:
                %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                if (app.is_sending)
                    app.sending_counter = app.sending_counter + 1; %Increase sending counter
                    app.Sending0Label.Text = ['Sending: ', num2str(app.sending_counter)]; %Update sending coouner text lable.
                end
                %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                

                %%%% Important %%%%
                %Short pause must be used in order to allow buttons callbacks to be responsive (you can also call drawnow).
                pause(0.01)
                %%%% Important %%%%
            end
        end

        % Button pushed function: StartSendingButton
        function StartSendingButtonPushed(app, event)
            app.is_sending = true; %Set flag to true when button is pressed.
        end

        % Button pushed function: StopSendingButton
        function StopSendingButtonPushed(app, event)
            app.is_sending = false; %Set flag to false when button is pressed.
        end
    end

    % Component initialization
    methods (Access = private)

        % Create UIFigure and components
        function createComponents(app)

            % Create UIFigure and hide until all components are created
            app.UIFigure = uifigure('Visible', 'off');
            app.UIFigure.Position = [100 100 440 304];
            app.UIFigure.Name = 'UI Figure';

            % Create StartSendingButton
            app.StartSendingButton = uibutton(app.UIFigure, 'push');
            app.StartSendingButton.ButtonPushedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @StartSendingButtonPushed, true);
            app.StartSendingButton.BackgroundColor = [0.3922 0.8314 0.0745];
            app.StartSendingButton.FontSize = 16;
            app.StartSendingButton.Position = [33 197 130 49];
            app.StartSendingButton.Text = 'Start Sending';

            % Create StopSendingButton
            app.StopSendingButton = uibutton(app.UIFigure, 'push');
            app.StopSendingButton.ButtonPushedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @StopSendingButtonPushed, true);
            app.StopSendingButton.BackgroundColor = [0.851 0.3255 0.098];
            app.StopSendingButton.FontSize = 16;
            app.StopSendingButton.Position = [33 129 130 49];
            app.StopSendingButton.Text = 'Stop Sending';

            % Create Sending0Label
            app.Sending0Label = uilabel(app.UIFigure);
            app.Sending0Label.FontSize = 16;
            app.Sending0Label.Position = [229 203 151 37];
            app.Sending0Label.Text = 'Sending: 0';

            % Create LoopCounter0Label
            app.LoopCounter0Label = uilabel(app.UIFigure);
            app.LoopCounter0Label.FontSize = 16;
            app.LoopCounter0Label.Position = [37 44 193 37];
            app.LoopCounter0Label.Text = 'Loop Counter: 0';

            % Show the figure after all components are created
            app.UIFigure.Visible = 'on';
        end
    end

    % App creation and deletion
    methods (Access = public)

        % Construct app
        function app = app1

            % Create UIFigure and components
            createComponents(app)

            % Register the app with App Designer
            registerApp(app, app.UIFigure)

            % Execute the startup function
            runStartupFcn(app, @startupFcn)

            if nargout == 0
                clear app
            end
        end

        % Code that executes before app deletion
        function delete(app)

            % Delete UIFigure when app is deleted
            delete(app.UIFigure)
        end
    end
end
```

You can copy and paste the entire code into an `m` file, to see how it works.

The code sample is not sending any data (and not related to Nucleo board), it's just advancing counters.

Here is how the sample application interface looks like:
[image]